# Only get Subscript out of range with those code , SOS

Tags: excel, vba

FILEPATH = "C:\Users\Chong\Desktop\COLD ROOM STOCK CONTROL.xlsx"

Workbooks.Open (FILEPATH)

But what I get was only "Subscript Out of range", Can anyone tell me where's the problem?

Comment: Is the path correct? is the workbook already opened?

Comment: I can't think of any situation that would produce that error from that code.

Comment: The workbook is not opened and the path is correct...... That's why I cant get what went wrong.